# If I have my own email server and domain, but use Outlook at the client, does this give Microsoft access to my emails?

Tags: email, outlook

I have a custom domain, and I'm going to set up an email server on a VPS.

Then I'm going to create an Outlook account and connect it to the email server via POPS/IMAP. How much does this compromise my privacy?

They key test is: Is Microsoft able to comply with a subpoena for my emails?

Is there anything I can do to increase my privacy? For example, is there a setting to only store data locally, or can I encrypt my email data at rest?

Comment: You want to know if your emails will flow through Microsoft's servers just by using the Outlook client and not using Microsoft email servers?

Comment: Are you talking about a web version of outlook or the traditional "offline" client? For the former, obviously, the answer's yes (from a technical view only, I'm no lawyer).